# Python - Sum values for year and name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have data that I want to sum for each year and player. The data resembles below

```
Out[28]: 
      Year            Player                 Tm   Yds
0     1970       Larry Brown  Arizona Cardinals  1125
1     1970       Ron Johnson  Arizona Cardinals  1027
2     1970    MacArthur Lane  Arizona Cardinals   977
3     1970      Floyd Little  Arizona Cardinals   901
4     1970      Larry Csonka  Arizona Cardinals   874
   ...               ...                ...   ...
1270  2020       Gus Edwards  Arizona Cardinals   723
1271  2020      James Conner  Arizona Cardinals   721
1272  2020     David Johnson  Arizona Cardinals   691
1273  2020     Damien Harris  Arizona Cardinals   691
1274  2020  Devin Singletary  Arizona Cardinals   687
```

So each year the "Player" "Yds" gets larger and I plan on plotting them for each year to see who has the most yards.

I have tried this below, but it just gives me to total of everyone;

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:RunningBackYards_3.csv', 
                 usecols=['Player', 'Tm', 'Year', 'Yds'])
r = len(df)

print(df.loc[1:r,['Yds']].sum())

counter = collections.Counter()
for ii in df.Player:
    counter.update(ii)
    
result = dict(counter)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby(['Player', 'Year']).sum()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess a `groupby` is more appropriate here. This should do the trick:

```
sum_df = df \
    .groupby(['Year', 'Player']) \
    .agg({'Yds': 'sum'})
```

Comment: It organizes the data, but it is not summing across the years. Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Code corrected for what works. The index of each player is found, and a for loop sums the first entry, then 2 entries, then 3 entries, etc.

```
df = pd.read_csv('D:\RunningBackYards_3.csv', 
                 usecols=['Player', 'Tm', 'Year', 'Yds'])

unique_player = set(df.Player)
unique_year = set(df.Year)  

        
yr = [[]]
plyr = [[]]
yards = [[]]

for ii in unique_player:
    idxPt = df.index[(df['Player'] == ii)]
    idx = 1
    for kk in idxPt:   
        yards.append(sum(df.Yds[idxPt[0:idx]]))
        yr.append(df.Year[kk])
        plyr.append(df.Player[kk])
        idx = idx + 1
        
yards = numpy.transpose(yards)
yr = numpy.transpose(yr)
plyr = numpy.transpose(plyr)

yards = pd.Series(yards)
yr = pd.Series(yr)
plyr = pd.Series(plyr)


data = {"Player": plyr,
        "Year": yr,
        "Yds": yards}

dffNew = pd.concat(data,
                   axis = 1)
```